# How can I make the equations with brackets to fit nicely into a list of items

Tags: enumerate, itemize, multicol

How can I make the equations with the brackets  fit in the items??

```
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[i.]
        \item $f(x) = \sqrt{3x+6}$
        \item $f(x) = \dfrac{x-1}{2x-8}$
        \item $f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{x^2+2x-3}+\frac{3x}{4x^2-4x+1}$
        \item
    \[ 
    f(x) = 
      \begin{cases} 
       x^3  &, x < 0 \\
       2x+3 &, x \geq 0
      \end{cases}
    \]
        \item
\[
f(x) = 
  \begin{cases} 
   x^5  &, x < -1 \\
   2x+3 &, x \geq -1
  \end{cases}
\]
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried changing `\[` to `$\displaystyle` and `\]` to `$`?

Comment: It's not clear what you want but you could use `$` for all the items, you use `\[` for the second two which forces the item label to be above the display math.

Answer (score 4):

Mico's suggestion resolves most of your issues. After replacing the `\[ ... \]` with `$ ... $` the remaining issue is with item `iii`, which doesn't seem to fit in a single line with the use of `multicol`. Using `$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$` resolves that.

[image]

#### Notes:

- I was planning of splitting the equation `iii` on two lines, but for some reason, that I don't know, using `aligned` allowed it to fit.
- Since you did not provide a complete  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages, your setup and the results may be slightly different.
- Also, your code shows the use of `multicols`, but the output does not.
- I moved the location of the commas, but if you don't like that, please feel free to move them back.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*]
    \item $f(x) = \sqrt{3x+6}$
    \item $f(x) = \dfrac{x-1}{2x-8}$
    \item 
        $\begin{aligned}[t]
            f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{x^2+2x-3}+\dfrac{3x}{4x^2-4x+1}
        \end{aligned}$
    \item
        $
        f(x) = 
          \begin{cases} 
           x^3,  & x < 0 \\
           2x+3, & x \geq 0
          \end{cases}
        $
    \item
        $
        f(x) = 
          \begin{cases} 
           x^5,  & x < -1 \\
           2x+3, & x \geq -1
          \end{cases}
        $
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!!